# Loading Django Admin and Django Rest Framework API to local website - 404 error

Tags: python, django, apache, django-rest-framework

I am trying to setup a local site visible on our local network (webdev.local). I can view the default apache page but cannot access the django admin or DRF API. I've checked the apache2.conf and the conf file I created for the virtualhost. I've seen plenty of references to the wsgi.py file but am not sure what's wrong with it. 
This was the first conf file I created:

```
Alias /static /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/static

  <Directory /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/name>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /static  /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/static

  <Directory /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/name>
      <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
      </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess name python-path= /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/name:/home/dbadmin/name/projectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup name
    WSGISCriptAlias / /home/dbadmin/name/django/name/name/wsgi.py
```

This is the second conf file I created after looking at Django 1.8 doc.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName webdev.local

  <Directory /home/dbadmin/appname/django/appname/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dbadmin/appname/django/name/name/wsgi.py

  <Directory /home/dbadmin/appname/django/appname/appname>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
  </Directory>  

    </VirtualHost>
```

Both work fine in localhost. Not sure what the issue is. Any advice or notice anything wrong???

Running Apache2 and Django 1.8 / Django Rest Framework 3.2.4